# Running multiple short lived java applications from one application

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have multiple monitoring applications which are cron scheduled and all these are managed through linux crontab scheduler.

I want to migrate all these to Quartz Scheduler so that it can be managed through one single application and based on their quartz cron, i will be invoking the underlying small application.

For such scenario, i want these small applications to run in a complete isolated environment so that they won't affect the other application which are scheduled by quartz.

I have found that Spring cloud task can support such thing but these apps are not spring based. They are simple java classes.

is there any other thing i can go with?

Comment: So, you want one application to trigger the other apps? And you also want to run the other applications each one to run in their own JVM instances?

Comment: yes, one application will trigger other application and it is not mandatory to run each application in their own JVM instances.

Comment: You may want to check our free and open-source QuartzDesk Executor app which is a clusterable Quartz-based app that comes with a bunch of "wrapper" jobs that allow you to easily run local and remote scripts / native applications, execute SQL queries / stored procedures etc. Most likely you will be able to use it as is without any changes. If you need to extend it, you can download the source code and add custom job wrappers etc. See https://github.com/quartzdesk/quartzdesk-executor.

Comment: it requires quartzdesk, which seems to be enterprise.

Comment: is there any other thing i can go for.